# Access actual values in a Keras custom loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a custom loss function that uses a relatively complicated algorithm to calculate a "score" based on the input features and the output value of the neural network. The model should then maximize the score. For this I would like to create a custom loss function that calls a regular Python function with numpy code. Sort of like this:

```
from Keras import ops

def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    squared_difference = ops.square(y_true - y_pred)
    return ops.mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)  # Note the `axis=-1`

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss_fn)
```

Unfortunately, this function gets invoked with so-called SymbolicTensors, which have no actual value. What I assume is happening, is that this function sort of "builds" a formula, which gets then uploaded to the Session device (GPU) and executed there entirely for each batch. Unfortunately, my use case requires the loss function to be calculated in Python on the CPU. So is there a way to access the actual batch values for the loss function and execute the loss function on the CPU given the input batch data and output batch data?

So that I can calculate the loss on the cpu using regular code and numpy?

Comment: Can you not just replace the `ops` commands with tf equivalents? It would be helpful to see an example why it should run on the cpu, with which commands.

Comment: I haven't written the code so I'm not sure. The code above is just representative.

Comment: If you "have to" calculate stuff on the CPU, presumably using arbitrary, non-TF Python code, I would bet that whatever you are trying to do will not work due to no gradients anyway. You need to use TF functionality for gradients, unless you define them yourself, I guess.

Comment: yeah now that I think about it, that makes sense.

Comment: if you use torch backend, how it goes? Does it return the actual value?